# Issue with Serial PINs (RX/TX) on Arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

I have an issue with an Arduino Nano.

I want to communicate with it through the Serial-Port. Meaning I want to send and receive Serial commands. With USB and the "Serial Monitor" this works nice.
Now I have connected the COM-Port of the PC with Adruinos Digital Pins 0 and 1 (RX and TX) and a GND PIN. (3 Cables total).

Here is a minimal example of my Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N1);
  Serial.println("Start");
}


void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hello World");

  delay( 1000 );
}
```

**The Serial Monitor says:**

```
Start
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
...
```

**Putty however says:**

```
▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒::
                                                     ▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒    ▒R▒▒▒t▒*▒▒▒R▒▒▒t▒*
```

Putty is connected with 
- BaudRate: 9600
- Data Bits: 
- Stop Bits: 1
- Parity: None
- Flow Control: None

What is wrong here?

Update:
The PC has a 9-pin D socket ([Image](http://www.airyear.com/images/products1/202711.jpg))
This is connected to a RS232 to RJ45 connector ([image](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41BucionchL._SY300_.jpg))
From the RJ45-Cable I used the Brown, Blue, and White/Green Cable to connect with the Arduino

Comment: Is this a 9-pin D socket built in to the PC?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RS232 is not TTL. You need a level converter. For more details see https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215.

Comment: Thanks. That's it! I just found it in the documentation: "Don't connect these pins directly to an RS232 serial port; they operate at +/- 12V and can damage your Arduino board." https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial